# References and Pointers both store addresses?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Does `int* var` and `&var` both store addresses, the only difference is that you have to deference `int*` to get the value back but don't references already do that? Having trouble understanding these thoroughly.

And why is that when you have a function that accepts int* into the parameters you can pass values in by &

Comment: That's typically how references are implemented, but the standard doesn't specify it.

Comment: And for the second question, it's just an unfortunate syntax choice that the same character `&` is used both for creating a pointer and specifying a reference. They have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Wow, that was a deluge of answerers...

Comment: @Deduplicator +1. I had to search ‘deluge’ though.

Answer (score 4):

They are different ways of expressing what probably eventually boils down to the same thing. They are both constructs that have been invented by the language's designers, meaning your compiler's authors must implement them in whatever manner they see fit for the underlying machine.

However, just because they may represent the same thing on the machine doesn't mean that they are equivalent. Pointers allow the concept of pointing-to-nothing-ness (NULL pointers) and also allow one to perform mathematic operations to obtain a portion of memory indexed off of a starting position... like so:

```
int *x = new int [10];
*(x+2) = 5; //set the 3rd element of the array pointed to by 'x' to 5
```

is perfectly sensible.

References have no notions of such things, i.e. one can do

```
int *x = new int[10];
*(x+2) = 5;
int &y = *(x+2);
```

but not

```
int *x = new int[10];
*(x+2) = 5;
int &y = *(x+2);
y = y + 5;//this just changes the value of x[2]
```

which means it's more difficult to write off the end of a struct because of bad pointer math, so they are safer provided they've been initialized to something that makes sense (i.e. not returned from a function where they are declared on the stack or to an array element that doesn't exist)

```
int &dontdoit() {
  //don't do this!
  int x = 7;
  int &y = x;
  return y;
}
```

I think this is perfectly legal and safe in that you won't be corrupting memory, but it's not recommended as you're mixing idioms and you have no way to free the resulting allocated memory:

```
int &dontdothiseither() {
  int *x = new int;
  int &y = *x;
  return y;
}
```

Also, you can set a pointer as many times as you like but not a reference.

```
int x[2];
int *y = x;//works
y = y+1; //works, now points to x[1];
int &z = x[0]; //works
z = x[1];//nope! This just sets x[0] to be the value in x[1]
```

Comment: Don't forget the `&vector[0]`-idiom. References are only safer because they always designate an object, they allow exactly the same shenanigans otherwise. Though they normally have different semantic meaning.

Answer (score 3):

`int*` is a variable whose value is the address of some `int`. `&var` is not a reference. The unary `&` operator simply returns the address of `var`. That's why if you have a function that takes a parameter of type `int*`, you use `&var` at the calling site.

It's a bit confusing since C++ uses `&` to mean both "address of" and "reference", but the context is what makes them different.

```
int a = 5;
int& ref = a; // Now ref and a both mean the same thing.
```

vs

```
int b = 6;
int* ptr = &b; // Now ptr POINTS to b, but they are not the same thing.
```

Answer (score 2):

no no no!
references become nickname of that variable, where as pointers store variable's address.
suppose we have a variable of type int :

```
    int x;

    int &y=x; // now y is an other name of x

    int *p=&x; // here p is a pointer, which points to x
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pointers and references both store addresses, and are compiled to exactly the same code. The only major difference though is that references cannot be null, whereas pointers can - hence the well-known "null-pointer". Obviously they are accessed in different ways by the *programmer*: using `->` and `.` respectively but that is really of no significance.

Comment: Many other differences - references can't be reseated (told to reference a different variable), therefore can't be default constructed, const references can extend the lifetime of a variable they reference.

Comment: Although it is not possible to have a null reference, it's possible to get an invalid reference by dereferencing a null pointer. Keep that in mind when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, internally passing a pointer to T and passing a reference to T are the same in any known sensible implementation, references being semantic sugar for pointers which are always dereferenced and cannot be `NULL`.
Implementations are not obligated to make sense though.

After optimization, that is even sure for references used inside a function.

Still, they lead to different method / object signatures.
Also, they have different semantic load for the reader.

Comment: A sensible implementation can assume that a reference is always valid and not allocate storage for it. References are not required to simply be pointers that automatically dereference themselves: they can be implemented more efficiently.

Comment: @bstamour: Added the non-NULL guarantee, which I plumb forgot to mention. All else was already there.

Comment: @bstamour: sometimes, but other times references are e.g. placed in structs/classes, or in a non-inlined function argument list, and must occupy storage (even if only a register in the latter case).

Comment: @Tony D absolutely. However I believe that equating references to being pointers that just auto-dereference is simplifying things too far. They are syntactically and semantically very distinct things.

Answer (score 1):

You can view a reference as a new "name" for a variable, while a pointer is a variable storing an address.

In practice, a reference might be implemented with pointers (so, it might store an address), but you do not need to worry about that.

For example:

```
int i;
int *pointer = &i;           //Holds address of i
int& reference = i;          //reference is a new name of i
int *pointer2 = &reference;  //pointer2 holds the address of i
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&` character is used for many different purposes in C++. Two of them look like they might be similar, but they're not.

The first is to create a reference:

```
int a = 1;
int &b = a;
```

Now `a` and `b` both refer to the same variable, and a change made to one will be reflected in the other.

The other usage is to create a pointer:

```
int *p = &a;
```

This has nothing to do with references at all. The `&` is being used as an address-of operator, taking the variable and creating a pointer that points to it.